# How to find something in all blueprints?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I need to find a certain block but I dont remember which blueprint it is so how to find anything in all blueprints ?

if this is not possible maybe a feature request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"uncheck the box on the far right side of the search. when checked it only searches the current BP."

https://forums.unrealengine.com/development-discussion/blueprint-visual-scripting/74992-how-to-search-all-blueprints-entire-project-for-values